# Laravel Redirect JPG, JPEG, and PNG images to WEBP using htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I'm not good about htaccess but I do have a script on htaccess that redirects an image to its equivalent webp file. It's working when my app is served via xampp but it doesn't work when I serve my app using artisan serve command. Can somebody help me with this? Here's my htaccess

```
# Default laravel htaccess script
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Script for redirect images to webp counterpart
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$ 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.webp -f
  RewriteRule (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$ %1\.webp [L,T=image/webp,R] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>

AddType image/webp .webp
```

Comment: `.htaccess` only works with Apache, so `php artisan serve` is not using Apache but the PHP built-in web server. You should also not be modifying the `.htaccess` but use the `routing` system it has, because this happens. Same would happen if you use NGINX as it does not use nor read `.htaccess`...

Comment: I see. Do you have any recommendation on how can I redirect this images to their webp files? I have a lot of <img> tags on my app and it's time consuming to change them one by one

Comment: You can take advantage of the Routing system, [regular expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) should help you here, make a regular expression for the name (any character) and another regular expression for the extension

Comment: "You should also not be modifying the `.htaccess` but use the `routing` system it has" - Although, if you don't modify `.htaccess` (when using Apache) then you would need to ensure the original `.jpeg`, `.jpg` and `.png` images have been removed from the filesystem in order to use the Laravel "routing system", otherwise Laravel is simply not called (so there is no fallback for browsers that do not support webp, which the current `.htaccess` rule provides). _Aside:_ The rule as posted is an external (temporary) `R`edirect - which is an "error" - it should be an _internal rewrite_.

Comment: ... the location of the current "webp" rule in `.htaccess` implies that the original `.jpg`, `.jpeg` and `.png` files still exist.